# How to implement the refresh token in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-redux, axios, refresh-token

The following code I did allows to refresh the access token, when on the first request the response return an Unauthorized,  run the service to refresh the access token.
The code works fine, the refresh token service runs on the backend made in Java.
The code is incomplete, there is only the call to the refresh token method.
On the following shown the code.

```
const apiMiddleware = ({ dispatch }) => (next) => (action) => {
  const result = next(action);
  if (action.type !== API) {
    return result;
  }
  const {
    url,
    method,
    data,
    onSuccess,
    types,
  } = action.payload;
  const axiosInstance = createAxios();

  const refreshToken = async(originalRequest) => {
    const axiosInstance = createAxios();
    const data = authUtil.getUserLoggedIn();
    const response = await axiosInstance({
      url: `${AUTH_ENDPOINT}/refresh-token`,
      method: 'PUT',
      data: { token: data.refreshToken },
    });
    if (response.status === 200) {
      authUtil.setUserLoggedIn(response.data);
      originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = response.data.accessToken;
      axiosInstance(originalRequest)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          handlerSuccess({ data });
          return result;
        });
    } else {
      dispatch(apiError(types[1], response.error));
    }
  };
  const handlerSuccess = ({ data }) => {
    dispatch(onSuccess(data));    
  };
  axiosInstance({
    method,
    url,
    data,
  })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      handlerSuccess({ data });
      return result;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 403) {
        dispatch(accessDenied(types[2], window.location.pathname));
      } else if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        refreshToken(error.config);
      }
      return result;
    })
};

export default apiMiddleware;
```

Somebody can help me to improve this code